# Using a function to populate a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have made a function that performs a random walk simulation (`random_path`) and returns a 1D array (of length `num_steps +1`). I would like to perform a large number of simulations (`n_sims`) using this function and then examine my results. I can do this using lists and for loops as:

```py
simulations = [] 
for i in range(0, n_sims):
    current_sim = random_path(x, y, sigma, T, num_steps)
    simulations.append(current_sim)
```

This works fine. I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way of doing this though? Is it possible to do this using only numpy arrays? That is, instead of setting up `simulations` as an empty list and then creating a list of arrays with a for loop, can I directly initialise `simulations` using the function `random_path` to create an array that I guess ultimately would be of shape `(n_sims, num_steps + 1)`?

Comment: To have a numpythonic solution, you need to show an MCVE that includes the functions in question.

Comment: List append is very 'pythonic'.  The only reasonable alternative is create a `simulations` of the right size and do `simulations[i]=current_sim`.  If `random_path` is complex enough, the iteration mechanism won't make much difference in time.

Comment: @hpaulj but not very "numpythonic" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you generate your random walk something like this (and if you don't, you probably should be):

```
walk = np.r_[0, np.random.normal(scale=sigma, size=N).cumsum()]
```

To make `M` simulations, just generate the appropriate number of data points and sum over the correct axis:

```
walks = np.concatenate((np.zeros((M, 1)), np.random.normal(scale=sigma, size=(M, N)).cumsum(axis=-1)), axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
simulations = [random_path(x, y, sigma, T, num_steps) for i in range(n_sims)]
```

If you don't want to explicitly use lists you can try with `numpy.vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np
vect_func = np.vectorize(lambda ignored: random_path(x, y, sigma, T, num_steps))
simulations = vect_func(range(n_sims))
```

In this particular case, `ignored` is, in fact, ignored.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have been clearer. Is there a way to do this without using lists at all?

Comment: @havingaball check it now, is this a better approach?

Comment: `np.vectorize` is a glorified python loop under the hood.